# Riehl's Category in Context - Example 2.1.5 (xi), Representable Functors

Tags: category-theory

"The functor iso: Cat → Set that takes a small category to its set of isomorphisms
(pointing in a specified direction) is represented by the category I, with two objects
and exactly one morphism in each hom-set".

So, if A and B are isomorphic in a category C, then we include only $f$ in our set $iso(C)$ (and not the inverse of $f$, since we are chosing isomorphisms pointing in a specified direction). Then, doesn't it suffice to have exactly one morphism in $I(a,b)$, where $a,b$ are the objects of $I$, and no morphisms in $I(b,a)$?

Comment: In that case the functor will represent all morphisms instead of isomorphisms

Comment: I see. So, if we make it such that all hom-sets in $I$ have exactly one element, how does that have a bijection with the isomorphisms in the given category $C$? I wasn't sure how to see it.

Comment: If all endomorphisms for both objects are automorphisms, and there exist maps going both directions between the two objects, then by composition all maps between those objects have to be  isomorphisms

Comment: The category with a map only in one direction is a free category on one morphism. Adding the map in the other direction is similar to going from a free algebra $k[x]$ to $k[x,y]/(xy_1) = k[x,x^{-1}]$. A map out of the former is an element of the target ring, whereas an element of the latter is a unit in the target ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question, I think it helps to first look a bit more closely at the category $I$. This category is sometimes call the "walking isomorphism" or the "free isomorphism". There are differnt equivalent ways to define it but the most common is the one you listed: $I$ is the category that has two objects, $0$ and $1$, and exactly one arrow in each hom-set.

What does this definition have to do with isomorphism? First, since $I$ is a category, it needs to have identities $1_0\in Hom(0,0)$ and $1_1\in Hom(1,1)$. But, since there is exactly one arrow in each hom set, these are the only arrows in these hom sets. So $Hom(0,0)=\{1_0\}$ and $Hom(1,1)=\{1_1\}$. But there are a few more hom sets, each with exactly one arrow. So $Hom(0,1)=\{f\}$ and $Hom(1,0)=\{g\}$, where $f$ and $g$ are just arbitrary names. So the category looks like this:

[image]

Now, since $I$ is a category, it must also contain the composite $gf$. But, by looking at the domain and codomain of $f$ and $g$, we can see that $gf\in Hom(0,0)=\{1_0\}$. So we must have that $gf=1_0$. We can similarly derive that $fg=1_1$. Thus, we must have that $f$ (and $g$) is an isomorphism!

Now lets see why $iso \cong Cat(I,-)$. Take any functor $F : I \to C$, i.e., an element of $Cat(I,C)$. Well, functors preserve isomorphism. So $F(f)\in C$ must be an isomorphism, with inverse $F(g)$! So any $F\in Cat(I,C)$ determines an element $F(f)\in iso(C)$. Now take an element $h\in iso(C)$. Since $h: x\to y$ is an isomorphism, it must have an inverse $h^{-1}:y\to x$. We can now define a functor $I\to C$ by specifying $0\mapsto x$, $1\mapsto y$, $f\mapsto h$, and $g\mapsto h^{-1}$, and sending identities to identities. Due to the way $I$ is defined, this fully specifies our wanted functor. And indeed, it is easy to verify that this mapping satisfies the functor laws. Whats important, though, is that $h$ is an isomorphism. If $h$ was not, then the mapping we defined would not satisfy the composition laws, also violating the theorem that functors preserve isomorphism.

Now, this is when thinking of $h$ as the isomorphism with inverse $h^{-1}$. We can also think of $h^{-1}$ as the iso, with inverse $h$. This would determine a different functor $F'$, that sends $f\mapsto h^{-1}$. But this would be a different functor. Of course, anytime we have one of these functors, we must have the other. But this is fine since any time we have an isomorphism, we must have a second isomorphism, its inverse.

It is a good exercise to prove that the correspondence between $iso(C)$ and $Cat(I,C)$ really defines a natural isomorphism. But I hope that the idea behind why $I$ represents $iso$, and thus earns the name "walking isomorphism" is much more clear.

What would happen if, as you suggest, we only require a morphism $f:0\to 1$? Well, there is actually a category like this, called the [walking arrow](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/interval+category) and often denoted $2$. The problem with this is that $f\in 2$ is not an isomorphism! Thus, there is nothing that guarantees $F(f)$ is an isomorphism, for $F:2\to C$. However, $2$ has an interesting property. Namely, $Ar \cong Cat(2,-)$, it represent the functor that takes a category to its set of arrows.